# Bash cannot create file

Tags: macos, bash, shell

So I'm trying to create a file in bash but I get a strange error, here is my code:

```
touch > "application/views/scripts/"$theFile"/"awk '{tolower($theFile".phtml")}'
```

Error:

```
./zf.sh: line 16: application/views/scripts/foo/awk: No such file or directory
```

I'm trying to create a file based on user input something like :`./zf.sh: line 16: application/views/scripts/foo/foo.phtml: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use awk:

```
fn=`echo ${theFile} | awk '{print tolower($0)}'`
touch application/views/scripts/"${fn}".phtml
```

Answer (score 1):

`touch application/views/scripts/"${theFile}"/$(echo ${theFile} | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]').phtml`

Answer (score 0):

With bash (version 4, I believe) you don't need any external tools

```
touch "application/views/scripts/${theFile}/${theFile,,}.phtml"
```

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion